# Current template file name with Template::Toolkit

Tags: html, perl, template-toolkit

I have read through the
[`Template::Toolkit` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template)
but could not figure out how to use `template.name` (the template being used). The string will be used to check =whether it's a particular template.

```
 [% SET name = template.name %]
  <span>[% IF name == 'ADMIN/MAIN.TT' %] YES [% ELSE %] NO [% END %]</span>
```

`template.name` returns `admin/main.tt` but it would not compare right. It keeps printing `NO`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String comparison is case sensitive in Template Toolkit.

```
[% IF name == 'admin/main.tt' %]
```

Comment: It must be `==`, not `=`.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr: Thanks, fixed.